# Windows NTFS - Add permission to each explicit ACL in all subfolders

Tags: windows, ntfs, file-permissions

We have a folder structure with many explicit rights like

```
root Folder
- subfolder 1 (explicit acl, no inherit acl)
- subfolder 2 (explicit acl, no inherit acl)
--subsubfolder 1 (no explicit rights, inherit acl)
--subsubfolder 2 (explicit acl, no inherit acl)
```

and so on

I want to add a permission (System Account) to all explicit ACLs but not to those which are not explicit. And of course there are some Folders which are not accessible even by an Administrator account, so I need to ignore Errors.

Anyone aware of an script which can achieve this?

**Edit1**
Thanks to Hardoman, here is a working solution for current folder, subfolder and files  and without catching the error...

```
$folders = (Get-ChildItem C:\Temp -Directory -Recurse) | select -ExpandProperty fullname
foreach ($item in $folders) {
    $inheritance = (Get-Acl $item).access[0] | select -ExpandProperty isinherited
    if ($inheritance -eq $false) {
            icacls.exe $item /grant 'System:(OI)(CI)(RX)'
    }
}
```

Didn`t found a solution with set-acl, maybe someone has an idea, this is my current set-acl state but the subfolder dont get the permissions even when they are inherited.

```
$folders = (Get-ChildItem C:\Temp -Directory -Recurse) | select -ExpandProperty fullname
foreach ($item in $folders) {
    $inheritance = (Get-Acl $item).access[0] | select -ExpandProperty isinherited
    if ($inheritance -eq $false) {
    try {
        $acl = Get-Acl $item
        $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("System","FullControl, Synchronize", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
        $acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
        Set-Acl $item $acl
    }
    catch {
        "Failed to access folder $item"
        "Exception type is $($_.Exception.GetType().Name)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `icacls` tool and add your preferred permissions. More details here: https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a Powershell script for that.
You need to recursively get all folders and subfolders, check inheritance for each and using **Get-ACL** and **Set-ACL** commadlets add permissions for the **system** account.
Try/catch will handle the errors in case script can't access the folder.

Here is the sample I wrote for you assuming that you recurse in C:\temp folder as an example.

```
$folders = (Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Directory -Recurse) | select -ExpandProperty fullname
foreach ($item in $folders) {
    $inheritance = (Get-Acl $item).access[0] | select -ExpandProperty isinherited
    if ($inheritance -eq $false) {
    try {
        $acl = Get-Acl $item
        $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ("System","FullControl","Allow")
        $acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
        $acl | Set-Acl $item
    }
    catch {
        "Failed to access folder $item"
        "Exception type is $($_.Exception.GetType().Name)"
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. For Get-ChildItem with -Directory to work you need to have Powershell 4+. This switch is missing in PS 2.0

Comment: Thanks so far for this one, have the Problem that now System is set at the correct folder(s) and when i add "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit" to the Access rule the permission is right on the folder which has set the permission...but all subfolders/files dont get the permission even when they are inherited. Any ideas on this? Found plenty of Topics regarding this with set-acl but no real solution except of using icacls.exe instead of set-acl